# `ng serve` error - how to trouble shoot?

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

I pulled down an older angular project of ours (maybe 6 months) and wanted to use it as a template. When I run it, I get the errors below. I googled and read a couple of [links](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9642) on google. None of them have suggestions past upgrading the versions of some packages, like angular/cli, which I did. I am at a bit of a loss on how to troubleshoot this.

I am having a hard time narrowing it down to a file too. Seems to be an issue with something called `raw-loader`, but that's not in my package json (guess its a dependency of something) and it looks like this, which obviously isn't the issue:

`/*
    MIT License http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
    Author Tobias Koppers @sokra
*/
module.exports = function(content) {
    this.cacheable && this.cacheable();
    this.value = content;
    return "module.exports = " + JSON.stringify(content);
}
module.exports.seperable = true;`

THE ERROR:
[image]

Installed package versions, if relevant:

``` angular-boilerplate@0.0.0 C:\code\go-local
+-- @angular/animations@4.4.6
+-- @angular/cli@1.7.2
+-- @angular/common@4.4.6
+-- @angular/compiler@4.4.6
+-- @angular/compiler-cli@4.4.6
+-- @angular/core@4.4.6
+-- @angular/forms@4.4.6
+-- @angular/http@4.4.6
+-- @angular/platform-browser@4.4.6
+-- @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@4.4.6
+-- @angular/router@4.4.6
+-- @types/jasmine@2.5.38
+-- @types/node@6.0.101
+-- angulartics2@2.5.0
+-- codelyzer@2.0.1
+-- core-js@2.5.3
+-- crds-ng2-content-block@1.1.1
+-- crds-reactive-auth@0.0.1 (git://github.com/crdschurch/crds-reactive-auth.git#a73d58905ca917badbd88131a92cf8c29f3cd629)
+-- crds-styles@2.2.1 (git://github.com/crdschurch/crds-styles.git#92c7c1926a2e3109401ddb583ebaa27cc9aa7221)
+-- intl@1.2.5
+-- jasmine-core@2.5.2
+-- jasmine-spec-reporter@3.2.0
+-- karma@1.4.1
+-- karma-chrome-launcher@2.0.0
+-- karma-cli@1.0.1
+-- karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter@0.2.3
+-- karma-jasmine@1.1.1
+-- karma-jasmine-html-reporter@0.2.2
+-- karma-mocha-reporter@2.2.5
+-- karma-phantomjs-launcher@1.0.4
+-- karma-teamcity-reporter@1.1.0
+-- ng2-mock-component@0.1.1
+-- ng2-toastr@4.1.2
+-- protractor@5.1.2
+-- rxjs@5.4.3
+-- ts-node@2.0.0
+-- tslint@4.5.1
+-- typescript@2.3.4
``-- zone.js@0.8.20 ```

`npm ERR! peer dep missing: ajv@^6.0.0, required by ajv-keywords@3.1.0
npm ERR! peer dep missing: ajv@^6.0.0, required by ajv-keywords@3.1.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the cli cannot get to some gyphicons used in bootstrap. I have run into this before and I would make sure your styles section in the angular-cli.json has a reference to the bootstrap directory in node_modules. Hope this helps.

Comment: This helped a ton. It was a style issue. I discovered a bunch of magical custom styles that break everything and fixed it. Thanks!